# GIMP open image as RGB layers

Tags: gimp

I'm a newbie on both Linux and Gimp.

[RGB Layers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ee6aD.png)

As you can see in the above picture, when I open a picture in GIMP, it separates the picture in 3 layers (R-G-B). But I don't want this, for now.

I want to image be opened as in one layer. But can't figure it out.

Looking forward to hearing from you, thanks.

Comment: What is the type of the picture? Not jpg / jpeg I assume.

Answer (score 0):

If the image is a TIFF (or PSD, or XCF) and really opens as three layers that represent the R/G/B channels(*), you can combine them all into a plain layer using `Layer>New from visible` and then removing the R/G/B layers.

(*) Other formats (JPG & PNG in particular) will always open as a single layer. So if this is is your source, make sure that you are looking at the Layers list (Ctrl-L) and not at the Channels one, because the Channelswill always show the 3 R,G,B channels of the visible image, even the image has only one layer.

Answer (score 0):

I see on picture **Channels** dialog window. To see **Layers** use hotkey <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd> or open it from menu:
Windows -> Dockable Dialogs -> Layers.